# How to change this JS script to issue a "GET" instead of a "POST" call

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this script:

```
        <script type='text/javascript'>
        $('#StdThemePropertyId').change(function () {
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
        });
    </script>
```

Which calls my MVC Controller to repopulate a child dropdown. The Child Dropdown is a "required" field so is throwing a validation error each time I try to filter it when selecting from the parent dropdown. I believe the answer is to simply alter the above script to issue a "GET" call. However my JS is a little lacking.

How can I alter the above JS to ensure a "GET" call is issued please.

Many thanks.

Comment: You'd have to change the form's method property to "GET" rather than "POST"

Comment: `"I believe the answer is to simply alter the above script to issue a "GET" call."` - What makes you think that?  A required field is a required field, regardless of how the data is sent to the server.

Comment: GET requests also run validation.  You need to change the server to not validate the request.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. The question you want to ask is: "How can I stop MVC from giving a validation error when I am trying to repopulate a drop down?" If you have to hack around the form to get something to work. Just stop, and think if maybe there isn't some other way you should be doing things.

Comment: @aquinas, Spot on..... Just realised that is my question. How do I filter a Child DropDown without triggering validation. Also just discovered I may also need to retain "POST" to persist field values.

Comment: @David, your point is also correct.

Comment: And @SLaks is correct. I would have put all of these in one comment, but can only put one name at a time.

Comment: I have now posted a new question on this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815829/how-to-deal-with-validation-when-filtering-dropdowns-in-a-mvc-form. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this line before the submit call...

```
$(this).parents('form').attr("method", "GET");
$(this).parents('form').submit();
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the form's method to get:

```
$(this).parents('form').attr('method','get').submit();
```